# Set properties/ data in VueJs Component

Tags: vue-component, vue-router, vuejs2

I have a VueComponent for which I need to pass a value "A". the problem is the value A can be passed VueRouter parameter or via the template interpolation. What is the best way to set a property data via both options?

e.g.

```
<component :property="value"></component>
```

if I navigate to

> /component/8/edit

```
mounted() {
   this.property = this._route.params.id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to figure out to which parameter you want to give priority, If you want to give priority to `route` param, you can do following:

```
mounted() {
   this.property = this.$route.params.id ? this.$route.params.id  : this.property
}
```

If you want to give priority to props being passed, you can write:

```
mounted() {
   this.property = this.property ? this.property : this.$route.params.id 
}
```

Comment: Slight off topic but related can a "data" property be a function when reference in the template syntax? i.e. `data{ return { property(){ return this.otherProperty } } }` or should it be left to computed because I want to do what you said and be able to override as needed

Comment: left a message for you in the chat